# How to find current git repository url by command line

Tags: git

I want to get the repository url so that I can connect to it from local repo.

I ssh into the remote repository, and now I need the url.
The remote repository however has a remote url of its own, if that matters.

So if I do `git config --get remote.origin.url` , it shows some remote address that's completely *wrong*.

So how do I get the url on the repo I'm currently ssh:ed into?

Comment: can you try with "git remote -v" ?

Comment: Assuming you mean "I have a window open and it's on some host, whose name I don't know, and I'm in some directory whose path I don't know; what URL reaches this directory on this host?": the answer is "nobody knows". A URL consists of a scheme (https:// or ssh:// for instance) followed by various parts such as host name and path; the scheme determines how the rest gets used; if it has a host name, in general the parts *past* the host name are passed on to that host, which interprets them as it sees fit.

Comment: What you'll need to do, then, is: discover what name reaches that host from your machine; pick a scheme (ssh perhaps) that gets you to that host; and find some path that, when presented *to* that host's server (ssh or http server for instance), locates the directory you're in. *Usually* you can use `hostname` and `pwd` and some mental arithmetic, as in [Özgür's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74572808/1256452).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ssh://username@example.com:12345/~/path/repository
```

where `~` means the home directory of the user and `path/repository` is the relative path of the repository to the home directory.

Comment: So this would be correct then? git remote set-url origin2 ssh://myuser@11.11.11.111:22/~/../../var/www/www.something.com/public_html.git
( i get error, but i don't know if it's the adress or it might be permissions, the error isn't specific..)